# Update a shared view from different controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view which is being rendered in a shared layout called  _Layout.cshtml.

_Layout.cshtml

```
<h1>@Html.Action("Home", "TestView");</h1>
```

Controller:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult TestView()
{
    var model = new TestViewModel();
    model.Title = "Default Title";
    return PartialView("/Views/Shared/_TestView.cshtml", model);
}
```

_TestView.cshtml

```
@model TestMVC.Models.TestViewModel
@Model.Title
```

So far everything works fine, but I want to know if it is possible to update the model from a different action/controller.
Example in: `localhost:8888/home/index`, I want to display the default title which is "Default Title", but in certain actions/controller ex `localhost:8888/home/contactus`
I want to display a different title ex. "Contact us form title".
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

just add an optional parameter:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult TestView(string title = "Default Title")
{
    var model = new TestViewModel{ Title = title };
    return PartialView("/Views/Shared/_TestView.cshtml", model);
}
```

then call it

```
<h1>@Html.Action("Home", "TestView", new { title = "Custom Title" })</h1>
```

or

```
<h1>@Html.Action("Home", "TestView")</h1> //use default title
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your partial view is between `<h1>` tags, does this mean it will only function as a placeholder for text?

Either way, I get the feeling there are better solution than using partial pages.

You could simply use `ViewBag` to set a chosen field, e.g. `ViewBag.CustomHeader = "Hello";`.

Then you can remove the partial view and reference that field:

```
<h1>@ViewBag.CustomHeader</h1>
```

**Keep in mind that you are then responsible for setting that value each time, or having the _Layout page provide a default value in case you didn't set it.**

```
<h1>@(ViewBag.CustomHeader ?? "No title was set!")</h1>
```

A second option is possible by using Razor's sections to set the header. This would allow even HTML to be entered if you so choose.

Change your `<h1>` (including the tags) to:

```
@RenderSection("CustomHeader", required : false);
//you can set required to true if you need it.
```

Then, on any View you render, you can add a section by that name, and it will be added on the _Layout page instead of the contained View.

```
@section CustomHeader {
    <h1>Hello, again! I'm another page!</h1>

    <!-- You can add anything you want here -->
}
```

More info on sections can be found [here.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx)